# missing destination file operand

Tags: linux

Can please somebody help me why does my script has an error `missing destination file operand`.

```
mv: missing destination file operand after/data/edbcp/tmpwks/d/gilbert_sample
Try mv --help for more information.
sh: line 1: /data/edbcp/tmpwks: is a directory
```

Comment: Please show us your code, from where supposedly this error is coming.

Comment: Looks like you didn't specify any destination to **move** your file to. Did you used the right syntax? `mv /path/to/source/file /path/to/destination/file` ?

Comment: Can you show me the full script

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to specify a place to move the file to.

Also, in `sh: line 1: /data/edbcp/tmpwks: is a directory`, it seems like you tried to call a directory like it is an executable.